# Writing One File To Another Produces Incorrect Results

Tags: c

The program opens a file in read mode. It then creates a second file, writes the contents of the first file into the second and deletes the first. It finishes by renaming the second file to the original name.

Here is the output I get.

```
User:~ ./main

Before
M1
M2
M3
M4

After
1
M2
M4
ÿ User:~
```

The output should read the same as the first excluding the second line because that is the line I want to delete.

This is the part of the code that copy's the characters.

```
ch = getc(File1);
while(ch != EOF);
{
    ch = getc(File1);

    if (ch == '\n')
        ln++;
    if (ln != LineToDelete)
    {
        putc(ch, File2);
    }
}
```

[Here is The Full Code On Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/xUs9Vtmd)

Comment: You should post all relevant code here, since the pastebin link may die, and the point of this site is for people with the same question to be able to get help at a later date.

Comment: Is this exactly copy-pasted from your real code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems that I see:

1. You are throwing away your first input character, because you read a character before entering your loop then immediately read another after entering.
2. You are not initializing `ln`.  It appears that you got lucky and it was already `0`, so you ended up omitting the line with "M3" rather than "M2".  However, you're dealing with undefined behaviour here; anything could have happened.
3. You are printing out the EOF character.

Try something like this:

```
ln = 1;
while (EOF != (ch = getc(File1))) {
    if ('\n' == ch)
        ++ln;
    if (LineToDelete != ln)
        putc(ch, File2);
}
```

Comment: The first character 'M' right before the 1 is still missing. However the EOF character is gone. Thank you.